# How to build a Pod as a framework

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I have a library project for Mac OS X and iOS. For Mac OS X, it shall build as a framework.

The project depends on a third party library for which a Pod exists. A client project which uses my project will require to link against that third party library as well, since it exposes a class from that third party library.

Now, for Mac OS X, without utilizing CocoaPods, it would be easy and quick to setup a project which build an executable which uses my library and compiles, links and runs fine:

- Build the third party library as a framework.
- Build my library project as a framework which links against the third party framework.
- Build the main executable which links against my library (as a framework) AND the third party framework.
- My own framework and the third party framework shall become "private" frameworks and put into the bundle of the executable.

Searching the CocoaPods Guide and the web didn't reveal anything which is remotely related to this.

So, how can I accomplish the setup as described above utilizing CocoaPods for the third party library and the dependencies, benefitting from semantic versioning and a (hopefully) streamlined setup?